# Creating folder in APPDATA folder on Windows XP (folder is read-only)

Tags: java, appdata

In my Java app I find the APPDATA folder and then attempt to create my own subfolder:

```
    if (System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows")) { 
        settingsDir = System.getenv("APPDATA") + "\\MyApp\\";

        if (!(new File(settingsDir)).isDirectory()) {
            if (!(new File(settingsDir)).getParentFile().mkdirs()) {
                Error("Failed to create directory " + settingsDir);
            }
        }
    }
```

On Windows XP this fails, saying the folder could not be created.

The hidden Application Data folder is read-only, and apparently this cannot be changed.

Could this be the reason why creating the new folder fails? If so, what would be the typical way to create a new folder in the APPDATA folder from Java?

Comment: Additionally, it seems that creating a file in the Application Data folder works fine, as opposed to creating a folder.

Answer (score 1):

Ouch, this appears to be a mistake in my own code. I had a left-over `getParentFile()` in the code. The correct version is:

```
if (System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows")) { 
    settingsDir = System.getenv("APPDATA") + "\\MyApp\\";

    if (!(new File(settingsDir)).isDirectory()) {
        if (!(new File(settingsDir)).mkdirs()) {
            Error("Failed to create directory " + settingsDir);
        }
    }
}
```

I was creating a folder in the *parent* folder of the APPDATA folder. This was not allowed.

Apparently, although the properties of the APPDATA folder say 'read-only', creating files and folders in this directory is allowed.

My bad, sorry for the noise. I will leave this topic here for the archives.